# How to keep a table hidden on load and then show it on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Hi I am trying to achieve the hiding and showing the table. while loading the page table should be hide and when I click button it has to visible. for that I have created a table under div and created a button and created script function.
        Here is table with div
     //div for table
                            
                                
                                    
                                        
                                            
                                                
                                                    Name of Company
                                                    Address of Company
                                                    Company Phone Number

Code for button,

```
<asp:Button ID="AddMore_Button" runat="server" Text="Add More" class="btn btn-primary" OnclientClick="AddMore_Button"/>   //button for displaying table
```

when I click the button nothing happens. 
        Here the script,

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#AddMoreDetails').hide()
                $('#AddMore_Button').click(function () {
                    $("#AddMoreDetails").fadeToggle('fast');
                });
            });
            </script> 

While page loading table is hiding but when I click button it is not triggering. Any help..??
```

Comment: Is your click event working . just check using your console

Comment: can you show html page.? aspx code

Comment: #Yo Yo : click event is fine. it is working. when I click button it is going to main page..

Answer (score 2):

the code you wrote works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/n3n82epr/

`$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#AddMoreDetails').hide()
        $('#AddMore_Button').click(function () {
            $("#AddMoreDetails").fadeToggle('fast');
        });
    });`

Maybe your HTML code has some incorrect tags inside. You can check your page with : https://validator.w3.org/

Comment: In jsfiddle its working fine like what I am expecting. But don't know in project it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work fine. The table will be visible on page load till the scripts run. So its better to add a style `display:none` to table.

Comment: Hi I have added but no use.

Comment: Can you please show me the entire HTML you are using?

Answer (score 0):

your code  works fine, please check your id/class name that you are specifying

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $('p').hide();
          $("button").click(function(){
            $("p").fadeToggle('fast');
    });
});
```